# Using Java Configuration with auditing in Spring Data JPA

Tags: java, spring, spring-data, spring-data-jpa

Java configuration was [introduced in version 1.2.0 of Spring Data](http://blog.springsource.org/2012/10/15/spring-data-release-train-arrived/), but I can't figure out how the java configuration for `<jpa:auditing>` should look like. I couldn't find any examples in the docs, neither did I figure it out by looking at the Spring Data JPA Source.

I'm suspecting it's not possible to translate `<jpa:auditing>` into java configuration, but as I couldn't find a Jira for the possibly missing feature, I'm unsure. Does anyone know if I still have to use XML configuration if I use Spring Data JPA with auditing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EDIT: This feature is available as of version 1.5 M1 of Spring Data. See the [ticket](https://jira.springsource.org/browse/DATAJPA-265) created by Alex Blomskøld for details.

Activating auditing is currently not supported by the JavaConfig means we introduced in 1.2.0. As we're planning to generally overhaul the auditing infrastructure anyway, would you mind filing a ticket against Spring Data JPA to capture that aspect of the story?