# How to configure auditing with java config

Tags: spring-data, audit

I'm trying to implement basic auditing using Spring Data JPA. From [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13166599/using-java-configuration-with-auditing-in-spring-data-jpa) question I learned that it is not yet possible to enable auditing using an annotation. So I have the following `applicationContext.xml` file in `src/main/resources`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:jpa="http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa/spring-jpa.xsd">

    <jpa:auditing />
</beans>
```

I have added the `@ImportResources("classpath:/applicationContext.xml")` to my Java Config file.

On my `AbstractEntity`(which is a `@MappedSuperClass`) I have the following:

```
@MappedSuperclass
public abstract class AbstractEntity {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;
    @Version
    private Integer version;
    @CreatedDate
    private Date createdDate;
    @LastModifiedDate
    private Date lastModifiedDate;

    // GETTERS AND SETTERS
}
```

Where `java.util.Date` has been imported. I have also tried with `JodaTime` but no change.

As far as I can tell this configuration should be sufficient to enable the auditing for dates. I have no need for the `@CreatedBy`or `@LastModifiedBy` audits, so I don't think I need an `AuditAware` bean...even so, I have tried adding it but also without luck.

How do I get basic auditing to work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, Spring Data JPA 1.5 M1 ships with @EnableJpaAuditing so that you don't need the extra XML file if you're able to upgrade to this version.

It seems like you're missing the declaration of the `AuditingEntityListener` in the JPA config (usually the `orm.xml` config file). See the [reference documentation](https://web.archive.org/web/20140811212823/https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/jpa.repositories.html) for details.

Comment: thanks for the reply, I am able to upgrade to that version and have added the annotation, the default values are fine for me, but I guess I have to supply a `dateTimeProviderRef`, I'm just not quite sure how to add this properly...`EnableJpaAuditing(dateTimeProviderRef = "dateTimeProvider")` and then define a bean with name `dateTimeProvider` which returns `CurrentDateTimeProvider.INSTANCE`?

Comment: The `CurrentDateTimeProvider` is used by default anyway. You only need to explicitly configure this if you want to customize the dates being set.